# Garbage collection on a local variable

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm a C++ programmer entering the world of Java.  And I cannot get rid of the bad feeling of having to let the Java garbage collector do my cleaning.

How, for example, will this code behave in Java?

```
public void myFunction() {
    myObject object = new myObject();
    object.doSomething();
}
```

Will the local variable object be deleted when myFunction() exits?

Do I have to set object to null before exiting, or will it be out of scope and be deleted by the GC?  Or, at worst, will it leak like it would in C++?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It will be garbage collected *at some point after it's no longer used*. I believe in current implementations of Java it will actually persist until the end of the method, whereas the garbage collector in .NET is more aggressive. (I don't know whether there are any guarantees even in Java. Normally you'd only *want* the local variable to persist beyond its last possible read when you're debugging.)

But no, you don't need to set the variable to null, and doing so would harm readability.

It's unlikely that the object will garbage collected *immediately* after the method exits; it's up to when the GC runs... and of course if anything else holds onto a reference to the object, it may not be eligible for garbage collection anyway. Don't forget that the value of the variable is just a reference, not the object itself. (That may take a while to get used to coming from C++.)

Comment: In previous implementations, it wouldn't actually persist until the end of the method?  That would be kind of odd...

Comment: @Erick: I was more trying to avoid the guarantee that *future* implementations would keep the local variable as a "root". The .NET CLR definitely doesn't, and indeed an object can be garbage collected *while an instance method is still executing "in" it* so long as the GC knows that nothing will reference any of its fields.

Comment: @Erick if `doSomething()` doesn't use any other fields or methods of the object, or the code can be JITed so that all fields are put into registers and all the methods inlined, then the object may be collected before `doSomething()` completes, let alone `myFunction()`. The only criteria is whether the meaning of the code changes.

Comment: The JLS mentions the case of an object which has its only reference(s) on the stack not being a root: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.6.1 "Another example of this occurs if the values in an object's fields are stored in registers. The program may then access the registers instead of the object, and never access the object again. This would imply that the object is garbage."

Answer (score 3):

GC does the job at least when memory limit approaches, since any object referenced by out-of-scope variables can be garbage collected, but there is an unexpected behavior of out-of-scope local variables of the last exited block.

To look under the hood, let us compare :

```
{
   final List myTooBigList = new ArrayList();
   ... overfill the list
}
somethingRunOutOfMemory();
```

`somethingRunOutOfMemory()` because `myTooBigList` were not GCable, despite not in scope anymore and more memory was claimed, unlike the following :

```
{
   final List myTooBigList = new ArrayList();
   ... overfill the list
}
Object fake = null;
somethingDoesNotRunOutOfMemory();
```

Affectation of `fake` moves the stack pointer back and let `myTooBigList` GCable, then GC does its work as soon as memory limit approaches.
The surprise is that (at least in the jvm I'm testing) we have to explicitely reuse stack at the same level. It would be expected that local variables be GCable as soon as the block is exited, but I guess it's a compromise with performance. It would complicate much the bytecode.

Like in C, local variables are located in stack beside frames.
The stack pointer reserves as much space as required for the local variables in scope.
Local variable of an { exited block } become GCable when stack is reused, that is: after a local variable is declared at the same stack level, after the function returns, or after an exit evaluation (catch, loop condition).

They are GCable after :

```
try { } catch : after exit by catch because catch reuses stack
for { } : after exit loop condition  because evaluation reuses stack
while { } : after exit loop condition because evaluation reuses stack
{ } declare=value : after any declaration+affectation that reuses stack
```

They are not GCable just after :

```
try { } : after nothing caught
for { } : after exit by break
while { } : after exit by break
do { }
if { }
{ }
```

NOTE : for a lab, run GC then compare a `WeakReference(my variable)` to `null`.

```
final WeakReference gctest;
{
   final List myTooBigList = new ArrayList();
   gctest = new WeakReference(myTooBigList);
   ... overfill the list
}
Object fake = null;
System.gc();
assert gctest.get() == null;
```

Answer (score 1):

It will go out of scope. In Java, when no-one is pointing to an object anymore, it will be garbage collected or at least it will be available for garbage collection. No need to set it to null here. Sometimes setting an object reference to null is needed if your object will live on in you App, but a reference it holds needs to be garbage collected. In this case you are choosing to release the reference.

Comment: (the -1 is for the scope part. Variable scope and object lifecycle are not related at all in Java. The second part is less incorrect, though the criteria is reachability rather than lack of references - if two objects 'point' to each other, but neither is reachable from any other object, then they will be garbage collected even though someone is pointing to them )