# Is there any consequences of setting an reference to null in java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

If I have a reference pointing to some some java object, and do something like:

```
myObject=null;
```

Will the "lost data" of the old object be correctly freed by the JVM Garbage Collector? Something similar in C (with a pointer, would result in trash and a possible memory leak).
I am using null attribution in a java program and would like to now if it is "safe".

Comment: Note that you're not setting an object to null -- you're setting a *reference* to an object to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, but you don't usually need to specifically do that.

Let's say your "myObject" is used in another object. At some point in the lifetime of your application's execution, this object will stopped being referenced by any other object, and thus will be marked for deletion by the GC. Them myObject will be marked for deletion as well. As soon as all references to a given object disappear, the GC will eventually reclaim the memory.

There are (rare) exceptions, like event handling, where the dependency between two objects cannot be properly automatically ended, and you may end up with a memory leak: when you subscribe to an event on another class, then the subscriber cannot be collected even when there's no "direct" references to it. In that specific case, it might be interesting to clear the link manually.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there are no other references to the object, this is a good way to free memory up for the GC. (Actually, aside from weak references and the like, it's basically the only way: make the object unreachable from any live variables.) Note that there is no schedule for when an object might get garbage collected once it becomes unreachable.

EDIT: As others have pointed out, setting myObject to null is unnecessary if myObject is going out of scope anyway. When the variable itself is no longer available as a path to reach the object it references, then it doesn't matter to the GC system whether or not it contains a reference or null.

Answer (score 2):

If `myObject` only holds memory ( say large internal array ), then setting this reference to `null` is enough.

If, on the other hand, it holds some other kind of resource that you've allocated ( `Closeable`, `Thread`, `ExecutorService`, etc ), you must take care to properly shut down these resources.

Even though some of them may have `finalize` method they may be called too late ( or even never ) for your system to have a desirable effect.

It is a very common mistake for somebody switching from C++ to Java, and I am guilty as charged here.  In my first real Java project I would periodically run out of file handle, because I was not calling `close` after being done with them.  Needless to say with a 512MB heap, GC would never feel the need to start finalizing my IO objects before it was too late.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that some objects need to be properly shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the purpose of the garbage collector in the JVM. The JVM may at some later time call the `finalize` method of the object, and then it may discard the associated storage.

Comment: It's dangerous to speak about finalize! (As I realise you know, due to your use of "may") - there is no guarantee that finalize will ever be called, and depending on platforms, JVMs and garbage collection mechanisms, it will be called at different times - this is more a comment to the OP, not to you Greg.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The object the reference pointed to is *eligible* for garbage collection (if there are no other *live* references to the object) when:

1. *The method returns* - if it was initially created with method local scope
2. *Immediately* - if it is an instance or class variable

Comment: The "and nothing else refers to it" condition also applies to the first case: if you create it with method scope but pass it around, and some other objects keeps a reference to it, it doesn't become eligible. (Note: I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: Objects don't really have "method scope", except as a possible hidden JITC optimization.  An object created within a method invocation is eligible to be collected as soon as there are no longer any references to it, even if the invocation that created it is still "live".

Comment: Moreover, the number of references is not important. If what referes to the object is also eligible to GC, the object is eligible. The important thing is that the object is not *reachable* anymore.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in Java local variables are GC's when the method returns (even if they would in theory be GC'd earlier) - I shall try to find references to back this up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138200/garbage-collection-on-a-local-variable

Comment: OK, I'm pretty sure I've read in the Snoracle docs that local variables are only GC'd  on method return (a reason for writing small methods) - however the above John Skeet quote is the best I can up with right now!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's sometimes a GOOD idea to set Java object references (pointers) null.  This may (if there are no other references to the object) "free" the object sooner than would otherwise occur.  This is especially helpful when you have large "networks" of intertwined objects.

At worst case, you're costing one additional memory store.